# Что делать, если идет DDoS на сервер с сайтом?

Tags: linux, веб-сервер, ddos

Есть VPS-сервер. На нем стоит связка Apache и Nginx, а также MySQL, PHP 7.4. Там размещено 2 сайта (один на поддомене). Оба подключены через Cloudflare.

Нагрузка обычно маленькая, т.к. один из сайтов - небольшой блог, а воторой - самописное сайт-приложение. Но если сейчас посмотреть через утилиты iftop и nload, то на сервер идут запросы с кучи IP скоростью почти до 80 Мегабит/с. Cloudflare не помогает, сайт лежит.

Что делать?

Comment: Http или https?

Comment: Nginx автоматически редиректит HTTP на HTTPS. Для HTTPS используется сертификат Cloudflare (режим Full (strict))

Comment: *Cloudflare не помогает, сайт лежит. Что делать?* — первый пункт на рекламной странице: [#1 DDoS attack protection](https://www.cloudflare.com/ru-ru/lp/overview-a/). следовательно одно из двух: 1. обращайтесь в их техподдержку. 2. меняйте на защиту от какой-нибудь другой компании.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку